# Retrieve Multiple lookup Values in a single Cell on Partial Match

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a range of store names and addresses in my sheet and i need to lookup all possible matches (partial or true) and list them infront of that record.
I have been somewhat successful in getting the total count of possible matches but not able to retrieve all matches except the first one.

Below is the link to sample screenshot of sheet.

-
[image]

Formula used:

```
Cell    Formula
E2 -    {=SUM(IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND(D2,$A$2:$A$28))),1))}

F2 -    {=IF(COLUMN(A1)=$E2,INDEX($A:$A,LARGE(IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND($D2,$A$2:$A$28))),ROW($A$2:$A$28)),COLUMN(A1))),"")}
```

Need help to extend this formula to next columns to get next partial match.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter the array formula shown in E2 you can then fill it down/across:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Tim. I got the solution. Somehow copy pasting formula was not working for me. I dragged the formula down and across.